# Selenium Console Output

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to make selenium take the information that is in the console for my IDE and to save it as a dynamic file instead of it being overwritten.

This is currently what I use to find the console log which works well.

```
 LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
 for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
     System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
```

My IDE then saves the output to a file. However, I was wondering if there was some way to just take the information from the console into a new file each time? I've done this with screenshots, but not too sure about the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that could facilitate an answer is to know what is your IDE and if you can configure this behavior of saving in a file.

Considering you can programmatically set configurations of the name of this output file, to make it unique, you could append the time since epoch to its base name.

In Python:

```
import time
sec_epoch = int(time.time())
```

In Java:

```
Date.getTime()
```

If you can not configure the output file name, you could execute your commands from the terminal and save the content to a file using [redirection](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-script-output/).

Comment: Your comment actually worked and made me have another idea where I could just add "-${current_date}.txt" into the output file name which makes it dynamic now.